# masonry.js won't shuffle

Tags: jquery, css, layout, jquery-masonry

I am trying to test out having a div with a toggle slideUp/Down button and have masonry shuffle to the new spots as usual. Once the toggle is pressed the hidden item slides up and down, but when I press the toggler, the content slides fine, but get overlapped by the div below and nothing shuffles. Any suggestions?

html

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
        Praesent id arcu nisl, sit amet hendrerit velit. Phasellus magna elit, 
        tincidunt at iaculis id, semper eget nunc. Duis pellentesque pretium euismod. 
        Etiam et arcu ut ligula bibendum ultricies. Cras fermentum, risus id lacinia hendrerit, 
        tortor urna adipiscing nunc, vitae aliquam odio velit eget nibh. Vivamus eget sapien erat, 
        a dictum enim. Fusce tincidunt, libero at rutrum mollis, magna elit ullamcorper nibh, 
        suscipit suscipit arcu orci at est.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
        Praesent id arcu nisl, sit amet hendrerit velit. Phasellus magna elit, 
        tincidunt at iaculis id, semper eget nunc. Duis pellentesque pretium euismod. 
        Etiam et arcu ut ligula bibendum ultricies. Cras fermentum, risus id lacinia hendrerit, 
        tortor urna adipiscing nunc, vitae aliquam odio velit eget nibh. Vivamus eget sapien erat, 
        a dictum enim. Fusce tincidunt, libero at rutrum mollis, magna elit ullamcorper nibh, 
        suscipit suscipit arcu orci at est.
    </p>
    <p>
        Praesent id arcu nisl, sit amet hendrerit velit. Phasellus magna elit, 
        tincidunt at iaculis id, semper eget nunc. Duis pellentesque pretium euismod. 
        Etiam et arcu ut ligula bibendum ultricies. Cras fermentum, risus id lacinia hendrerit, 
        tortor urna adipiscing nunc, vitae aliquam odio velit eget nibh. Vivamus eget sapien erat, 
        a dictum enim. Fusce tincidunt, libero at rutrum mollis, magna elit ullamcorper nibh, 
        suscipit suscipit arcu orci at est.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
        Praesent id arcu nisl, sit amet hendrerit velit. Phasellus magna elit, 
        tincidunt at iaculis id, semper eget nunc. Duis pellentesque pretium euismod. 
        Etiam et arcu ut ligula bibendum ultricies. Cras fermentum, risus id lacinia hendrerit, 
        tortor urna adipiscing nunc, vitae aliquam odio velit eget nibh. Vivamus eget sapien erat, 
        a dictum enim. Fusce tincidunt, libero at rutrum mollis, magna elit ullamcorper nibh, 
        suscipit suscipit arcu orci at est.
    </p>
    <div class="toggler"><a href="#">toggle</a></div>
    <p class="hidden">
            This is the hidden text for the toggler.This is the hidden text for the toggler.
            This is the hidden text for the toggler. This is the hidden text for the toggler.
            This is the hidden text for the toggler. This is the hidden text for the toggler.
            This is the hidden text for the toggler. This is the hidden text for the toggler.
    </p> 
    <p>
        Praesent id arcu nisl, sit amet hendrerit velit. Phasellus magna elit, 
        tincidunt at iaculis id, semper eget nunc. Duis pellentesque pretium euismod. 
        Etiam et arcu ut ligula bibendum ultricies. Cras fermentum, risus id lacinia hendrerit, 
        tortor urna adipiscing nunc, vitae aliquam odio velit eget nibh. Vivamus eget sapien erat, 
        a dictum enim. Fusce tincidunt, libero at rutrum mollis, magna elit ullamcorper nibh, 
        suscipit suscipit arcu orci at est.
    </p>
    </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
        Praesent id arcu nisl, sit amet hendrerit velit. Phasellus magna elit, 
        tincidunt at iaculis id, semper eget nunc. Duis pellentesque pretium euismod. 
        Etiam et arcu ut ligula bibendum ultricies. Cras fermentum, risus id lacinia hendrerit, 
        tortor urna adipiscing nunc, vitae aliquam odio velit eget nibh. Vivamus eget sapien erat, 
        a dictum enim. Fusce tincidunt, libero at rutrum mollis, magna elit ullamcorper nibh, 
        suscipit suscipit arcu orci at est.
    </p>
  </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #D8D5D2;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  float: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          border-radius: 5px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
     $('#container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.item',
        isAnimated: true
     }),

     $(".toggler").click
        (
            function($e) 
            {
                $(".hidden").slideDown("normal");   
            }
        );

    $(".toggler").toggle
        (
            function($e) 
            {
                $(".hidden").slideDown("normal");
            },

            function($e) 
            {
                $(".hidden").slideUp("normal");
            }
        );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Masonry.js only triggers animation when the container is resized. That is why the animation function is called on the container div and not the individual divs. You can confirm this by going on their demo and using firebug/dev tools to hide divs. Nothing happens until the container is resized. The first line of the animation section (http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/animating.htm) also states it can be animated on container resize, which I would take to mean that is the only method for triggering the animation.

A possible solution may be to resize the container as part of your toggle. You will probably need to look at the plugin to see exactly how it determines when it has been resized, but I would guess even expanding it by a pixel would trigger the animation. I would assume it determines the new positions for each div after resize, so I would hide first then trigger the container resize. This probably isn't the best method, but the easiest way I can figure to get it to do what you want.